# can't perform array validation (out of bounds) - java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm not too sure on what's happening here.

Code is supposed to validate an input against an array of fixed ID numbers. But everytime I purposefully enter the wrong number, it would say that "array is out of bounds".

Not too sure on what is causing the problem, maybe someone can point out my mistake?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
 public class isValid
{
    static int accNum[] = {11111, 22222, 33333, 44444, 55555, 66666, 77777, 88888, 99999, 10101, 20202, 30303, 40404, 50505, 60606, 70707, 80808, 90909};

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    int conti = -99;
    int search = 0;
    do
    {
        System.out.print("Enter 5-digit account number you want to validate: ");

        search = keyboard.nextInt();

        sequentialSearch(accNum, search);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Enter -9 to exit program, or any other number to validate another ID: ");
        conti = keyboard.nextInt();

    } while (conti != -9);
}

public static void sequentialSearch(int[] array,int value)
{
    int index = 0;        
    int element = -1;      
    boolean found = false;    

    while (!found && index < array.length)
    {
        if (array[index] == value)
        {
            found = true;
            element = index;
            break; //prevent index addition if value found
        }
        index++;
    }

    if (array[index] == value)
    {
        System.out.println("Account " + value + " is valid.");
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Account " + value + " is invalid.");
    }
}
}
```

Problem given: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKiWP.jpg
Error message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lFzg.jpg

Comment: Firstly why are you using accNum directly in your sequentialSearch function when you are clearly passing it as an argument array as well?? This is not related to issue but needs to be reviewed.

Comment: @UsamaZafar -  ok, I fixed that

Comment: Look at the answers section you will find pretty good detail there.

Comment: @UsamaZafar I am really sorry for my prev. answer. It was abit dumb and I checked it in only in single way. But didn't view what happens if value is invalid. Thank u very much for your suggestion that encouraged me to look closely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the code and it should be something like this:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class isValid
    {
        static int accNum[] = {11111, 22222, 33333, 44444, 55555, 66666, 77777, 88888, 99999, 10101, 20202, 30303, 40404, 50505, 60606, 70707, 80808, 90909};

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

            int conti = -99;
            int search = 0;
            do
            {
                System.out.print("Enter 5-digit account number you want to validate: ");

                search = keyboard.nextInt();

                sequentialSearch(accNum, search);
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.print("Enter -9 to exit program, or any other number to validate another ID: ");
                conti = keyboard.nextInt();

        } while (conti != -9);
    }

    public static void sequentialSearch(int[] array,int value)
    {
        int index = 0;        
        int element = -1;      
        boolean found = false;    

        while (!found && index < array.length)
        {
            if (array[index] == value)
            {
                found = true;
                element = index;
                break; //prevent index addition if value found
            }
            index++;
        }

        if (found)
        {
            System.out.println("Account " + value + " is valid.");
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Account " + value + " is invalid.");
        }
    }
  }
```

Notice the change in the if condition present after the while loop of sequentialSearch function.

Why is that? Since the index is equal to the a value that is beyond the array indexes in case the value is not present in the array.

Comment: Should've used the boolean value to determine the if-else from the start. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I am really sorry that my previous solution was a little bit dumb, But now what I can suggest as second way of your solution is do like this,

```
while (!found && index < accNum.length)
{
    if (accNum[index] == value)
    {
        found = true;
        element = index;
        System.out.println("Account " + value + " is valid.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Account " + value + " is invalid.");
        break;
    }
    index++;
}
```

Description :- *Your value will be matched once and prints `valid` message. If it didn't match the value then it will print invalid message and loop will break.*